# textfile to jlabel and jlabel compared to textfile

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

so i was making an gui about an ATM system 
what i want to do is when the costumer enter his/her account number and pin the program will search for it in the DATABASE.txt and when it matches with the info from the DATABASE.txt.The program will automatically display the Name,AccountNumber,Age,Sex and Balance. but in my case im getting this error and i dont know how to fix it. plzz help me.i'll be grateful if you help me :) Thank you and cheers :). 
ps. i hope you guys understand my souce code T^T.

1st CLASS

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Xavier1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener,Runnable
{
JButton a[] = new JButton [10];
JLabel pin,acc;
JTextField acc1;
JButton del,ok,crt;
int c=0,d=0,e=0;
JPasswordField pin1;
JFrame x;
String us,pw;

public void run()
{

}

public Xavier1()
{
    x = new JFrame("ATM");
    x.setLayout(null);
    x.setBounds(400,100,550,500);
    x.setVisible(true);

    JPanel x3 = new JPanel();
    x.add(x3);
    x3.setVisible(true);
    x3.setBounds(150,420,250,100);
    crt = new JButton("Create Account");
    crt.addActionListener(this);
    x3.add(crt);

    JPanel x2 = new JPanel();
    x.add(x2);
    x2.setBounds(150,10,250,100);
    x2.setVisible(true);
    x2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
    pin = new JLabel("PIN");
    acc = new JLabel("ACCOUNT NUMBER");
    pin1 = new JPasswordField(20);
    acc1 = new JTextField(20);

    x2.add(acc);
    x2.add(acc1);
    x2.add(pin);
    x2.add(pin1);


    JPanel x1 = new JPanel();
    x.add(x1);
    x1.setBounds(150,200,250,200);
    x1.setVisible(true);
    x1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));

    for(int b=0;b<10;b++)
    {
        a[b] = new JButton();
        a[b].setText(Integer.toString(b));
        x1.add(a[b]);
        a[b].addActionListener(this);
    }
    ok = new JButton("OK");
    ok.addActionListener(this);
    del = new JButton("DEL");
    del.addActionListener(this);
    x1.add(ok);
    x1.add(del);




}
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Xavier1 xs = new Xavier1();
    Thread xd = new Thread(xs);
    xd.setDaemon(true);



}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent z)
{
    Object zz = z.getSource();

    if(e == 0)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<a.length;c++)
        {
            if(zz == a[c])
            {
            acc1.setText(acc1.getText()+a[c].getText());
            }

        }
    }
    if(zz == ok)
    {
        e++;
    }
    if(e==2)
    {
        GateKeeper();


    }
    if(e == 1)
    {
        for(int d=0;d<a.length;d++)
        {
            if(zz == a[d])
            {
            pin1.setText(pin1.getText()+a[d].getText());
            }

        }

    }
    if(zz == crt)
    {
        Reg rs = new Reg();
        Thread sr = new Thread(rs);
        sr.start();
        x.setVisible(false);
    }
    if(zz == del)
    {
        if(e == 0)
        {
            acc1.setText(null);
        }
        if(e == 1)
        {
            pin1.setText(null);
        }
    }

}
public void GateKeeper()
{
    try
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("DATABASE.txt"));
        int loop = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for(int gk=0;gk<loop;gk++)
        {
            String ps[] = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            us = ps[0];
            pw = ps[1];
            if(acc1.getText().equals(us));
            {
                if(pin1.getText().equals(pw))
                {
                    Bank b = new Bank();
                    Thread xb = new Thread(b);
                    xb.start();
                    x.setVisible(false);

                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException s)
    {

    }
}
}
```

2ND CLASS

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Reg extends Bank
{
JButton res,back,next;
JFrame r;

public Reg()
{
    r = new JFrame("REGISTRATION");
    r.setVisible(true);
    x.setVisible(false);
    r.setBounds(400,100,550,500);
    r.setLayout(null);
    X.setVisible(false);

    n = new JLabel("Name");
    age = new JLabel("AGE");
    sex = new JLabel("SEX");
    dep = new JLabel("DEPOSIT");
    accn = new JLabel("ACCOUNT NUMBER");
    pins = new JLabel("PIN");
    n1 = new JTextField(20);
    accn1 = new JTextField(20);
    bal1 = new JTextField(20);
    sex1 = new JTextField(20);
    age1 = new JTextField(20);
    dep1 = new JTextField(20);
    pins1 = new JPasswordField(20);

    JPanel r1 = new JPanel();
    r.add(r1);
    r1.setVisible(true);
    r1.setBounds(50,10,400,400);

    r1.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,2));

    r1.add(accn);
    r1.add(accn1);
    r1.add(pins);
    r1.add(pins1);
    r1.add(n);
    r1.add(n1);
    r1.add(age);
    r1.add(age1);
    r1.add(sex);
    r1.add(sex1);
    r1.add(dep);
    r1.add(dep1);

    JPanel r2 = new JPanel();
    r.add(r2);
    r2.setVisible(true);
    r2.setBounds(130,400,300,50);
    r2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));
    back = new JButton("BACK");
    next = new JButton("NEXT");
    res = new JButton("REGISTER!");
    res.addActionListener(this);
    back.addActionListener(this);
    next.addActionListener(this);
    r2.add(back);
    r2.add(res);
    r2.add(next);

}
public void DATABASE()
{
    try
    {

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("DATABASE.txt",true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    pw.print(accn1.getText()+" ");
    pw.print(pins1.getText()+" ");
    pw.print(n1.getText()+" ");
    pw.print(age1.getText()+" ");
    pw.print(sex1.getText()+" ");
    pw.print(dep1.getText()+" ");
    pw.println();
    pw.close();


    }
    catch(IOException s)
    {

    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{


}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent rg)
{
    Object rz = rg.getSource();

    if(rz == res)
    {
        DATABASE();
    }
    if(rz == next)
    {
        Bank b = new Bank();
        Thread xb = new Thread(b);
        xb.start();
        r.setVisible(false);
    }
    if(rz == back)
    {
        Xavier1 xs = new Xavier1();
        Thread xd = new Thread(xs);
        xd.start();
        r.setVisible(false);
    }

}
}
```

3rd CLASS

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Bank extends Xavier1
{


JLabel n,accn,bal,age,sex,dep,pins;
JFrame X,r;
JTextField n1,accn1,bal1,sex1,age1,dep1;
JPasswordField pins1;
JLabel Xn,Xacc,Xbal,Xage,Xsex;
String xn,xacc,xbal,xage,xsex;

public void reader()
{
    try
    {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("DATABASE.TXT");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException s)
    {

    }
}


public Bank()
{
    X = new JFrame("BANK");
    X.setVisible(true);
    X.setBounds(400,100,550,500);
    X.setLayout(null);
    x.setVisible(false);


    JPanel info = new JPanel();
    X.add(info);
    info.setVisible(true);
    info.setBounds(50,10,400,400);
    info.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,2));

    try
    {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File("DATABASE.txt"));
        int loop2 = s2.nextInt();
        for(int gkz=0;gkz<loop2;gkz++)
        {
            String info2[]= s2.nextLine().split(" ");
            xn   = info2[2];
            xacc = info2[0];
            xage = info2[3];
            xsex = info2[4];
            xbal =info2[5];

            if(acc1.getText().equals(us))
            {
                if(pin1.getText().equals(pw))
                {
                    JLabel Xn= new JLabel("NAME: "+xn);
                    JLabel Xacc = new JLabel("ACCOUNT NUMBER: "+xacc);
                    JLabel Xage = new JLabel("AGE: "+xage);
                    JLabel Xsex = new JLabel("SEX: "+sex);
                    JLabel Xbal = new JLabel("BALANCE: "+xbal);

                }
            }


        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException s)
    {

    }





}
public static void main(String args[])
{


}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent z1)
{
    Object z2 = z1.getSource();
}

}
```

THIS ARE THE ERRORS I GET

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at Bank.<init>(Bank.java:54)
at Xavier1.GateKeeper(Xavier1.java:160)
at Xavier1.actionPerformed(Xavier1.java:108)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: i dont know how to fix them :( sorry im still a newbie :( it just pinpoint to the GateKeeper and i dont seem to know whats wrong. btw ty for helping me sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2`
>   (Bank.java:54)
>
> (Bank.java:54) - `xn   = info2[2];`

Here's your problem. Say your file is like this

```
3
data data data data
data data data data
```

The first line in thw code below will read the `3` but the scanner will stay on that line.

```
int loop2 = s2.nextInt();  
for(int gkz=0;gkz<loop2;gkz++)
{
    String info2[]= s2.nextLine().split(" ");
```

So the next call to `nextLine()` will consume only consume the line carriage and will only *take* you to the next line, but not actually *read* it.  So really the `s2.nextLine().split(" ");` will return an empty array. So when you try and do `info[2]` you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because index 2 doesn't exist.

Two possible fixes.

1. Just call `s2.nextLine()` after `int loop2 = s2.nextInt();`
2. Personally though, I prefer to *always* read by lines (instead of nextInt/nextDouble) and parse it so I don't run into the problem you are.

   ```
   int loop2 = Integer.parseInt(s2.nextLine().trim());    
   for(int gkz=0;gkz<loop2;gkz++) {
       ...
   ```